# Range of a random variable

Tags: statistics

A set of notes i'm working through gives the following definitions of the range of a random variable and then in addition a variation of the definition.

Definition: The range of a random variable is the smallest interval that contains all the values of the random variable.

A variation of the last definition says that the range of a random variable is the smallest interval that contains all the values of the random variable with probability 1.

It then gives the following example
Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Let $X = 1/Z$ if $|Z|>1$; $X = Z$ if $0<|Z|<1$, and $X =1000$ if $Z = 0$. Then the range of $X$, according to the first definition, is $(0,1000]$, but according to the second definition the range of X is $(0,1)$.

Should it not be $(-1,1000]$ in the first case and $(-1,1)$ in the second? Since $Z$ is defined on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ And so when $Z$ is arbitrarily close to $-1$ $X$ is arbitrarily close to $-1$?

Answer (score 0):

You're right; it's an error in the notes.